# Imagens com tamanhos diferente no woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Estou montando uma loja virtual para minha esposa e estou com um problema. Estou usando o WooCommerce com o tema Wootique. Ao inserir imagens no produto, mesmo tratando no Photoshop e deixando as duas imagens com o mesmo tamanho e resolução, na tela de produtos as imagens aparecem com tamanhos diferentes. Não consigo padronizar o tamanho. O site ainda está em testes e com domínio temporário.
Envio abaixo duas páginas para exemplificar o que estou dizendo. Queria a imagem do tamanho dessa (http://fredloja.zz.vc/produto/mocassim-azul-com-bordado-branco/) mas algumas ficam diferentes, como por exemplo (http://fredloja.zz.vc/produto/sapatilha-preta-com-marrom-e-fivela-dourada/). 
Alguém saberia me dizer como devo proceder para corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Coloco as imagens no produto e quando vou no site, na página de cada produto, os tamanhos estão diferentes. Coloquei dois links na pergunta onde pode ser visualizado o problema. No Mocassim o tamanho está maior e no sapatilha está menor. Os arquivos das fotos possuem as mesmas dimensões.